# How to make UI and Text effect in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make my UI and Text appear like this in Unity

[image]

Kinda lost, don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is combination of two things:

1. Glowing image. Which move over button.
2. Button's image.

   ```
    "Image Type": Filled.
    "Fill Method": Horizontal. 
     and some other settings Here is the reference image.
   ```

   [image]

> **Animations:**

For animation of glow and image fill you could use unity **animation** and **animator** but i think that will be over kill for such process so i will suggest to use **tween** plugin like **DoTween** (My personal Best, Free), **ITween** (Free), **HoTween**(Free), **Easy Tween**(Not Sure) etc.

> **Arrangement:**

Arrangement of this is easy and can be achieve like this:

Button game object having child game object with image component.
Then moving glowing game object over button.

If you need more information about animation and tween plugins or anything relevant to this then let me know...

I Hope this will help.

Comment: sorry for late reply, when i try to import dotween, there is erros. Failed to copy package file to Assets/Demigiant/DOTween/Editor.meta ..and the importing popup just got stuck until i close unity

Comment: Humm... never seen such a issue. Restart unity over again and try to rem import it. If it didn't work then delete Library folder  from the project and restart unity. By restarting unity Library folder will be recreated but to be safe make sure to have back up, if you are using git hub then do commit or Stash to save your changes.

Comment: thanks, it work, i'm looking at dotween document at the moment

Comment: sure do read the documentation and if you need any help with do tween then let me know and you can also get my personal email form my profile.If my answer was helpful then accept my answer by pressing "Tick" button near up/Dow vote.